# workflow Register Error

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

Hello Can you help me?

*-Errors :

Register Workflow to SharePoint :the massage of error 
[image]
I am doing certificate ...that configuration:
IIS Manager > Sites > workflow site > Bindings > https >Edit > view > Certificate > Details > Copy to file > Certificate Export Wizard:  *No, do not export the Private key  > next > *DER encode binary X.50(.CER)>next>save File name...C:/>finish

Now Go to SharePoint central administrator > Security >Manage Trust >New > Name… Root Authority Certificate *Browse > C: / certificate Name.. Chose > ok

Then go to SharePoint management Shell and re right Command >>>
Ohhh It’s the same of Error 
What’s The Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here , the root chain of the certificate is not installed in the MMC , while registering any certificate in SharePoint , its root certificate and intermediate certificates need to be installed in MMC .

[image]

and you can identify the certificate path from the iis and it should be shown without any errors.

[image]

if there is any errors shown here in certificate status , then it need to be taken care.

Comment: This is not a problem .. I'm so sure

Comment: have you checked the certificate status in IIS as as shown above ? is there any error or status ok?

Comment: sure... i am checked from this

Comment: i have single server DC,SQLServer,IIS,workflow in one server >>That is the problem